# WCF Shorten Field names (XmlElement)?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service where i'm sending a list of 'Item's to process, several hundred. Ideally to reduce traffic I'd like to shorten property names by marking them as like so..

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "u")]
    public int  UserID   { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "c")]
    public string   Code     { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "d")]
    public DateTime Date    { get; set; }
}
```

However checking the traffic with fiddler the long names are still transmitted, ie UserID, Code, Date.

Any thoughts on how I can get WCF to use short names?

Comment: Just as a side comment, if bandwidth usage is your main concern, you might want to consider to enable compression on your service host given your clients can handle it

Comment: Ah ok, good suggestion. you mean like gzip in IIS?

Comment: Yes, should only require you to install & enable compression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be the `XmlElement` attribute, you can use the [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute (possibly together with the `DataContract` attribute on the class) and set it's [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name.aspx) property accordingly.

For example:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization; // Add Reference to "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"

[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "u")]
    public int  UserID   { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "c")]
    public string   Code     { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "d")]
    public DateTime Date    { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this has the following effect though (which is logical if you think about it): if you use the resulting WSDL description to (re)generate a C# class from it using `svcutil.exe`, it will look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember()]
    public int  u   { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public string   c     { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public DateTime d    { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to this, and have the client under your control as well, you can share the Item class definition with the client (i.e. via common assembly containing it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and example, appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute, and supply a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, for WCF it is

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember (Name="u")]
    public int UserID   { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name="c")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name="d")]        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and example, appreciated